# Ah freilichen purim .. English please

Tags: purim, translation, yiddish, social-convention

I was wondering how to say *Ah freilichen Purim* in proper English. 
Is it universal like *Gut Yomtiv* (or is that also an assumption...) or do you just say Have a Happy Purim - the literal translation. ( I have a co-worker that’s not from my background and I want to make sure I address him properly without offending him )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It literally means "a festive Purim". The words "I wish you" that should accompany it are missing but if you want to say it in proper English then "I wish you a festive Purim" would do the job.

Google Translate has "A happy Purim".

Maybe you need to cast lots to decide which to use. ([Purim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim) means "lots").

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok Thanks for response. As there are presumably no sources possible for an answer here, I am looking for someone who interacts with those non-yiddish/yeshivish speaking. Is that your case (sorry for being nosy, but otherwise you didn't really answer my question)

Comment: @R.Mo I do interact with non-yiddish/yeshivish speakers.

Comment: I fail to see why "I wish you a joyful Purim" would not be OK to say to a Yeshivish person as long as you don't start singing "I wish you a joyful Purim and a happy Nissan!"

Comment: @Mike My question was about insulting someone by belittling their jewish knowledge. - shoulda had ignorance as a tag.  :)

Comment: Wow I found his answer very helpful. I am teaching in a Orthodox Jewish School and they often use words I don't understand so I look them up. I have started studying Hebrew because I love languages and my students all study it. I try to say the words correctly and they will giggle. When I write my newsletter I just use English words.
Have a blessed Chanukah! :)